# Dystopian novel where you're given a number corresponding to your career

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

I read this probably in middle school, around 2012, but I'm sure the year isn't reliable enough to go off of and it is probably older. I can't recall if it was in-person or if this was a random book I stumbled upon on the Nook.

It was a dystopian book where society revolved around taking a test as a young adult (the age was probably 10-16) that tested multiple skills, I believe, and you were given a number based off of your answers/performance, most likely 1-4. Your number corresponded to the types of careers you could have and there was a stigma around lower numbers; the parents all wanted their children to get high numbers.

The book starts off not long before the main character (whom I believe is a boy) is set to take his test, and I think his dad gives him some sort of weird hat (it's described as strange). The test is at some sort of huge stadium and it's packed; the friends go their separate ways to take their tests. I forgot what the test specifically included, but I think at the last part they're sitting in a room with someone as they're given their number. He ended up getting a 0 which apparently had never happened before and was led away and was now on the run.

He ended up returning home and the door to his room wasn't there, like it had never existed, and the room was completely empty like his parents never had a child (pretty sure he was an only child). You find out later that they had went to a psychic who had saw that something bad would happen during the testing and this was their way of protecting themselves, as I think reaching too low of a score meant the city would take you away and exile your family.

He goes on the run after that and ends up meeting with his friend, whom I believe had become an apprentice for a baker. She gives him bread and they catch up (I believe they talk through a city gate) and she mentions that their friend had gotten too low of a score and that she wasn't allowed to talk to him anymore.

I could possibly be getting details mixed up with other dystopian books I read at the time, but I for sure know the details about the hat, 0 and 1-4 scores, the missing door, and the apprentice baker girl should all be accurate. I really enjoyed the book and, believe it or not, it's been on my mind on and off for all these years. It'd be great to be able to reminisce and end the story.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/10476572-scored - Quite a common trope in YA fiction...